# Flutter: rebuild ListView from ListTile

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a `ListView` inside of a `FutureBuilder`. This `FutureBuilder` loads a list from disk and once loaded, shows a `ListView`. This `ListView` has a custom `ItemTile` to show for each loaded item. Each `ItemTile` has a button to copy itself (i.e. writing a copy of itself to memory). How can I now inform the `ListView` to be rebuild?

This is how my `ItemTile` is implemented (I only included the relevant code).

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
    child: Card(
      semanticContainer: false,
      //This flag should be false if the card contains multiple different types of content.
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width: double.infinity,
        child:
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: getPopUpMenuButton(context),
            )
      ),
    ),
  );
}


PopupMenuButton<String> getPopUpMenuButton(BuildContext context) {
return PopupMenuButton(
  onSelected: (str) {
    switch (str) {
      case 'MAKECOPY':
        {
          Item newItem = Item.clone(this.item, sameUID: false);
          Scaffold.of(context).setState(() {
            _itemManager.save(newItem);
          });
        }
    }
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
  itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
    new PopupMenuItem<String>(
        value: 'MAKECOPY',
        child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).get('edit_as_copy'))),
  ],
);
}
```

I assumed the `Scaffold.of(context).setState` would do the trick but it does not. How do I correctly call a rebuild of the `ListView`/`FutureBuilder` from a list item?

Comment: This is probably a use-case for a larger state-management system, like bloc or redux.

Comment: Call setState inside a custom function in the widget class where you have FutureBuilder and then pass that function to your custom ListTile use it to rebuild the future builder.

See if you can use StreamBuilder instead of a future builder, that would make things a lot easier.